# zip_longest without fillvalue

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-itertools

I am searching for a middle ground between Python's `zip` and `zip_longest` functions (from the *itertools* module), that exhausts all given iterators, but does not fill in anything. So, for example, it should transpose tuples like so:

```py
(11, 12, 13    ),        (11, 21, 31, 41),
(21, 22, 23, 24),  -->   (12, 22, 32, 42),
(31, 32        ),        (13, 23,     43),
(41, 42, 43, 44),        (    24,     44)
```

<sub><sup>(Spaces added for nicer graphical alignment.)</sup></sub>

I managed to compose a crude a solution by cleaning out the `fillvalue`s after `zip_longest`.

```py
def zip_discard(*iterables, sentinel = object()):
    return map(
            partial(filter, partial(is_not, sentinel)), 
            zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel))
```

Is there a way to do this without introducing the sentinels to begin with? Can this be improved using `yield`? Which approach seems most efficient?

Comment: I am not sure whether this question is on-topic on [so]. Don't you think it would be better if you posted it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I decided for Stack Overflow because this question asks for the most efficient way and Python answers here often include timing comparisons. But as I was unsure myself, I would not object to a migration.

Comment: are you looking for a generator, or iterator, solution?

Comment: Both would do, I only require something iterable for further processing.

Comment: When working with sentinels you want to compare object *identity*, so you should use [`op.is_not`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html) instead of `op.ne`.

Comment: @Bakuriu corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Both `zip` and `zip_longest` were designed to always generate tuples of equal length, you can define your own generator that doesn't care about the len with something like this:

```
def _one_pass(iters):
    for it in iters:
        try:
            yield next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            pass #of some of them are already exhausted then ignore it.

def zip_varlen(*iterables):
    iters = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while True: #broken when an empty tuple is given by _one_pass
        val = tuple(_one_pass(iters))
        if val:
            yield val
        else:
            break
```

If the data being zipped together is fairly large then skipping the exhausted iterators every time can be expensive, it may be more efficient to remove the finished iterators from `iters` in the `_one_pass` function like this:

```
def _one_pass(iters):
    i = 0
    while i<len(iters):
        try:
            yield next(iters[i])
        except StopIteration:
            del iters[i]
        else:
            i+=1
```

both of these versions would remove the need to create intermediate results or use temporary filler values.

Answer (score 7):

You approach is good. I think using a sentinel is elegant. I might be considered a bit more pythonic to use a nested generator expression:

```
def zip_discard_gen(*iterables, sentinel=object()):
    return ((entry for entry in iterable if entry is not sentinel)
            for iterable in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel))
```

This needs fewer imports because there is no need for `partial()` or `ne()`.

It is a bit faster too:

```
data = [(11, 12, 13    ),
        (21, 22, 23, 24),
        (31, 32        ),
        (41, 42, 43, 44)]

%timeit [list(x) for x in zip_discard(*data)]  
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.5 µs per loop

%timeit [list(x) for x in zip_discard_gen(*data)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.2 µs per loop
```

**EDIT**

A list comprehension version is a bit faster:

```
def zip_discard_compr(*iterables, sentinel=object()):
    return [[entry for entry in iterable if entry is not sentinel]
            for iterable in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel)]
```

Timing:

```
%timeit zip_discard_compr(*data)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.73 µs per loop
```

A Python 2 version:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

SENTINEL = object()

def zip_discard_compr(*iterables):
    sentinel = SENTINEL
    return [[entry for entry in iterable if entry is not sentinel]
            for iterable in izip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel)]
```

### Timings

This version returns the same data structure as `zip_varlen` by
Tadhg McDonald-Jensen:

```
def zip_discard_gen(*iterables, sentinel=object()):
    return (tuple([entry for entry in iterable if entry is not sentinel])
            for iterable in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel))
```

It is about twice as fast:

```
%timeit list(zip_discard_gen(*data))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.37 µs per loop

%timeit list(zip_varlen(*data))
10000 loops, best of 3: 18 µs per loop
```

Comment: I like this, but on my system (i5 haswell laptop, python 2.7), the list version is a little faster (6.22 uS vs. 6.62 uS). also, `zip_discard`, since it returns lists, doesn't really require casting to list, so with that out it reduces to 5.61 uS, which is a little faster again. note that I did have to modify the code slightly - python 2.7 didn't like `*data` before the `sentinel` keyword arg, which would make it awkward to use... but sentinel could easily be module-global (to where this is defined) without any ill effects...

Comment: Just changing the `()` into `[]` turns the generator expressions into list comprehensions. No need anymore to convert the result into a list of lists.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Added a list comprehension version. It is about twice as fast if you are going for the list of lists anyway.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: I'd be curious about scalability, if the list of iterators was `random.sample([range(i) for i in range(1e6)], 1e6)`  to have 1 million iterators that go up to 1 million elements whether my version that drops iterators as they finish would be faster. for smaller lists obviously the difference in doing the _one_pass in python vs zip_longest which is done in C makes all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve this without a sentinel (not even in the interim) yielded some interesting insights.

```
m = (
  (11, 12, 13,       ),
  (21, 22, 23, 24, 25),
  (31, 32,           ),
  (41, 42, 43, 44,   ),
)

result = [[r[i] for r in m if r[i:i+1]] for i in range(0, max(len(r) for r in m))]
```

First insight, I've been using python for long enough that I'll constantly question the use of indices. There is always a better way. ALWAYS.

Second insight, a slice returns an empty tuple where ref by index would cause an IndexError. Replacing `r[i:i+1]` with `len(r) < i` would work in this example.

So what do I think is the better way? Using a fillvalue and then filter to strip out the value if you must.

```
t = tuple(zip_longest(*m))
t_clean = [list(filter(None, r)) for r in t]
m_again = tuple(zip_longest(*t))
```

The `zip` transposing idiom is not easy to grasp but worth learning. Transposing again yields the original which can't be done without a missing placeholder. Can also "skip" values. Considering we're all putting in spaces to make the matrix legible, we all want the placeholders there. If `m` was created with the infill value it would equal `m_again`, which is a nice property. Prioritise developer performance, the real bottle neck.